# Why was this question (with a low view count) protected?

Tags: discussion

I post on SF from time to time and I noticed that my question [IPSec L2L Failover between two pfSense devices](https://serverfault.com/questions/487684/ipsec-l2l-failover-between-two-pfsense-devices) had been protected. Given that the view count is low and there is no reason to think there will be a deluge of answers, why might this question be protected? I am not questioning the decision, I just want to know the process.

Comment: Because taco overflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the question and the answers that were deleted from it, I'd suggest it was protected because it was acting as a magnet for low quality posts that were really just people asking the same sort of thing as you, over and over.

Comment: This is indeed exactly what was happening.